# How to create html <ul> tag ID dynamic in asp.net?

Tags: html, css, asp.net, eval, asprepeater

I want to create dynamic id for  tag that reside on Repeater control

```
<ul class="collapse list-unstyled sideSubMenu" id='<%# "sidemenu" + "" +  Eval("ModuleID")%>'>
```

but it can't work.

Please give way to solve it, your response is valuable.

Answer (score 0):

You can use `String.Format` to concatenate id:

```
<ul class="collapse list-unstyled sideSubMenu" id='<%# String.Format("sidemenu{0}", Eval("ModuleID") ) %>'>
```